# How to add action from redux connect to component props typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to declare props in my react component. Here is code:

```
interface HeaderProps {
  getUserData: typeof _getUserData;
}

const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({ getUserData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  return <div>Test</div>;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUserData: _getUserData,
};

export default connect(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

But TS is throwing error. I have tried to rewrite `connect` like this
`connect<{}, HeaderProps>(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps)(Header);`
But it have not worked.
I have tried to look for answer in the web, but was not ably to find any.
TS Error:

```
rgument of type 'FC<HeaderProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ getUserData: () => Promise<void>; }, HeaderProps>>'.
  Type 'FunctionComponent<HeaderProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<{ getUserData: () => Promise<void>; }, HeaderProps>>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<HeaderProps> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<{ getUserData: () => Promise<void>; }, HeaderProps>> | undefined'.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<HeaderProps>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<{ getUserData: () => Promise<void>; }, HeaderProps>>'.
          Types of property 'getUserData' are incompatible.
            Type 'Validator<() => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, getState: () => {}, api: AxiosStatic) => Promise<void>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<() => Promise<void>> | undefined'.
              Type 'Validator<() => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, getState: () => {}, api: AxiosStatic) => Promise<void>>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<() => Promise<void>>'.
                Type '() => (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, getState: () => {}, api: AxiosStatic) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<void>'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a [solution](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component). In `react-redux` they have added `ConnectedProps`.
So I have changed code to this:

```js
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

type Props = PropsFromRedux;

const Header: React.FC<PropsFromRedux> = ({ getUserData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  return <div>Test</div>;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUserData: _getUserData,
};

const connector = connect(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
export default connect(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your mapDispatchToProps needs to be function, passing in dispatch and wrapping your action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
       getUserData: bindActionCreators<any, any>(_getUserData, dispatch)
    }
}
```

Also if you're not passing any props through on the mapStateToProps function you can just pass through a null.

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: mapDispatchToProps don't need to be a function.
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops
`null` is not what caused errors

Comment: @KostyaTresko have you actually tried it the way I posted? I have at least 30 functional components in my ts 3.7 project that work perfectly like that